# How to open page in window

Tags: wpf

There is a window on how to make it so that after clicking on the button, a page opens inside this window, while it moves along with the window, the background of the window darkens and when you click on, all the elements of the window become non-clickable.

[image: Left: A window with content. Right: The window with content has an overlay with page content. The transition between both is triggerd by a button click.]

Comment: Posting some code to understand you problem is helpful. And be more specific about your problem. That black window seems to be a ``ContentDialog``, but it's unclear what is your problem.

Comment: @Andrew KeepCoding I want to do something similar to what is in discord, when the "what's new" window appears on top of the main interface elements at startup, the main interface becomes non-clickable, and the background is shaded

Comment: In WinUI 3 we have the [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/dialogs-and-flyouts/flyouts) control which shows focus on the top and make the background disabled-ish. But in WPF AFAIK, there's no built-in control for this. [MahApps](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/flyouts) might be an option but I never used it.

Comment: If you are looking for a modern-looking UI, consider WinUI 3.

Comment: Does anyone know how to open a page in the "Flyouts" element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need actual Flyout. The combination of ordinary `Grid`s would surffice.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="800" Height="400">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Main content -->

        <!-- Flyout Grid -->
        <Grid Visibility="Visible"
              Background="#22000000">
            <Grid Width="400" Height="300" Background="Black">
                <TextBlock Text="Flyout" Foreground="White"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This Flyout Grid covers the entire Window and looks as a Flyout. You can show/hide this Grid by changing its `Visibility` somehow by binding.

**Edit**

Assuming you have a `System.Windows.Controls.Page` named "FlyoutPage", You can add it in design time:

```xml
<!-- Flyout Grid -->
<Grid Visibility="Visible"
      Background="#22000000">
    <Grid x:Name="FlyoutGrid" Width="400" Height="300" Background="Black">
        <Frame>
            <Frame.Content>
                <local:FlyoutPage/>
            </Frame.Content>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You can add it at run time as well.

```cs
this.FlyoutGrid.Children.Clear();
this.FlyoutGrid.Children.Add(new Frame { Content = new FlyoutPage() });
```

Comment: If you do this, then the pop-up window is located under other elements

Comment: No. The elements writen in lower in xaml will be drawn on top.

Comment: How to put a separately created page in this "grid"?

Comment: Do you want to add it run time or design time?

Comment: Well, it is desirable that it was during the year, but it is also necessary to know how to add by default during interface development

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to the default WPF controls, you could check out [Material Design in XAML](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/). This library provides a `DialogHost` control which does exactly what you want. For more information, please refer to the Wiki on [Dialogs](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs). The library is available as NuGet package [MaterialDesignThemes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialDesignThemes/).

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost>
   <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
      <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="This is the dialog content."
                    Margin="10"/>
         <Button Content="Close dialog"
                 Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"/>
      </StackPanel>
   </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
   <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
           Content="Open dialog"
           Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

There is the regular content and a dialog content, as well as special commands for open and close.

[image: A window with a button to open a dialog and a dialog on top of it with a text and a button to close it. The window content is grayed out.]